# at they satisfy the equation 2−2+=0 A 2 − 2 B + I = 0 and 2–2+=0

Tags: matrices

Let A and B be 4 * 4 matrices with real entry, such that they satisfy the equation
$A^2-2B+I=0$ and $ B^2–2A+I=0$. Given that |A-B| is non zero, find the value of det|A+B|.

I subtracted both the equations
So i got $ A^2-B^2$ = 2(B-A) now if i can say A and B commute then i will be able to further solve. Can i say A and B commmute?

Comment: $A^2-B^2=?$; second attempt...

Comment: don't you see that $A^2=B^2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Make a power four eqn in A.
$(A-I)^2 (A^2+3A+5I) =0$. Answer come s out to be 16

Comment: Your formula $(A-I)^2(A^2+3A+5I)=0$ is false and your answer also.

Answer (score 1):

$B$ commutes with $A$ because $B$ is a polynomial in $A$.